# ErrorException Object of class Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile could not be converted to int

Tags: laravel, controller

My Store Controller Code is given below.
imagaes folder is kept on both public and project folder file. but can't convert to int.
in Live Database images save like sample.jpeg but it should be e code like 123456.sample.jpeg

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|image',
        'priority' => 'required',
        'button_link' => 'nullable|url',
    ], [
        'title.required' => "please provide a slider title", 
        'priority.required' => "please provide a slider priority ",
        'image.required' => "please provide a slider image ",
        'image.image' => "please provide a slider image ",
        'button_link.url' => "please provide a slider button link ",
    ]);

    $slider = new Slider();
    $slider->title = $request->title;
    $slider->image = $request->image;
    $slider->buttone_text = $request->buttone_text;
    $slider->button_link = $request->button_link;
    $slider->priority = $request->priority;

    if ($request->image > 0) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $img = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $location = 'images/sliders/'.$img;
        Image::make($image)->save($location);
        $slider->image = $img;
    }
    $slider->save();

    return back()->with('success', 'A new slider has addedd succesfully');
}
```

Please clarify what is the error of this code.If a insert the image file name e.g 123456.sample.jpeg then it works.
but if i insert it by website admin then it can't store image info correctly. It stores sample.jpeg instead 123456.sample.jpeg .So it caught an error
ErrorException Object of class Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile could not be converted to int
So whats the problem behind this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `hasFile` method provided by Laravel's request object instead of `if($request->image > 0)`. You can't compare an image with an integer.

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $img = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $location = 'images/sliders/' . $img;
    Image::make($image)->save($location);
    $slider->image = $img;
}
```